# Hey, I've recently learned recurrsion and i want to know why isnt my code working it's in c

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, printf, function-definition

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print(int a[],int size)
{ int i=0;
if (size!=0) //4<4
{
    printf("%d",a[i]);
    return print(a[i+1],size-1); 
}

}
int main()
{ 
    int n,a[100],size;
        printf("Enter array size");
    scanf("%d",&size);
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("Enter number u want to enter");
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
 printf("%d",print(a,size));

}
```

I want it to take the size which is 3 for examples and have array of 5 4 2 and print them out in sequnece 5 4 2 but instead, it runs and everything and takes the input but does print again the output.

Comment: How do you define `not working` in this context?

Comment: idk it works like it runs but it doesnt print the output it only takes it

Comment: You maybe need a `\n` in your printf statements to write the output.

Comment: it doesnt write anoutput it only takes inputs and stops

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the input you use, the output you get (ar state that you don't get any output) and the expected output you want to get.

Comment: Explain the comment `4 < 4`.

Comment: Surely you get compiler warnings.  Address them.

Comment: Try to implement recursion as clear as possible. (1) the recursion anchor / terminator comes first: `if (x) return y;` (2) for every recursive call make sure to change the recursive input parameters **in a way so you can prove** that you get closer to the terminator condition `x`. Like, if x is `a < 1` then make sure that for every recursive call `a` is smaller than before.

Comment: Questions like this sound to me like "I've recently learned recursion and now it's everyone else's problem!"

Comment: I would suggest starting from indenting your code correctly. It will help you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function name `find` (that is used in your question before updating it) is confusing. You are trying to find nothing  in the function.

Your function actually returns nothing. So the return type `int` does not make a sense.

Thus this call

```
printf("%d",print(a,size));
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

In this call

```
return find(a[i+1],size);
```

the expression `a[i+1]` has the type `int` instead of the `int *` that is required by the function declaration. Moreover the variable `i` is always equal to `0` in each recursive call of the function due to its declaration

```
int i=0;
```

If you want just to output an array then the function can look for example the following way

```
void print_array( const int a[], size_t size)
{
    if ( size != 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d", *a );
        print_array( a + 1, size - 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: what is const? and size_t

Comment: @NadineMohamed The qualifier const means that the passed array is not changed within the function. As an array can not have negative number of elements then the number of elements should be specified using an unsigned integer type. The type size_t is the type of an expression used in the operator sizeof.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code.  Perhaps the most significant are:

```
if (i<size+1)
```

If the array `a` is only `size` elements long, then the behavior when attempting to read from `a[size]` is undefined. In your case, if `size < 100` this won't be an issue, but that ought to be `if( i < size )`.

And:

```
return find(a[i+1],size);
```

`find` expects an `int *` as its first argument, and you are passing an `int`.  The value of `a[i+1]` is certainly not a valid memory location (indeed, `i+1` is beyond the bounds of `a`, so merely attempting to read `a[i+1]` is undefined behavior), so the first time `a` is accessed in the call will lead to undefined behavior.  Instead, try `find(a + 1, size - 1)`.

Once you fix those issues, the codes should "work".

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find(int a[],int size){
  int i=0;

  if (i<size){
      printf("%d",a[i]); //5
      find(a[i+1],size);
  }

}

int main(){
  int n,a[100],size;

  printf("Enter array size");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
      printf("Enter number u want to enter");
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }

   find(a,size);
}
```

Comment: The title says you've learned recursion, but the code proves you did not. Maybe explain how `find` is intended to work.